# Junit on Netbeans doesn't work

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I know that netbeans has an existing junit plugin but for some reason it doesn't work properly with my code:

```
public int Add(String a, String b){
  int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
  int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
  return x + y;
}
```

Junit test class was generated that contains the following test case:

```
public void testAdd() {
  System.out.println("Add");
  String a = "2";
  String b = "3";
  TestingProject2016 instance = new TestingProject2016();
  int expResult = 5;
  int result = instance.Add(a, b);
  assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

The junit shows that this test fails saying that there is initialization error, although it should be a success since it returns a correct value based on the code above.

[image]

Any idea what went wrong?

Note: that I am using Junit 4. Thanks :)

Comment: Not enough information. Can you add junit output? Or you can debug this method.

Comment: junit output screenshot is added to the question

Comment: You say you are running JUnit 4 but it looks to me as if you have generated a JUnit 3 test.  Does your `testAdd()` method have a `@Test` annotation?  Does your test class `TestingProject2016Test` extend `TestCase`?

Comment: Which of my two questions have you just answered?

Comment: I chose Junit 4 in the beginning but no idea what's the difference

Comment: both questions --> no extension and no @Test

Comment: In JUnit 3 (before Java 5 and annotations) test classes extended `TestCase` and all methods whose name began with `test` were test methods.  In JUnit 4, test classes no longer need to extend any class, and test methods are indicated by putting the `@Test` annotation on them.  As you say you're using JUnit 4, try putting the `@Test` annotation on your test method.

Comment: That worked out :D

Comment: Thanks bro.. u r the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the fix was to add the `@Test` annotation to the test method.

The `@Test` annotation on a method is used to tell JUnit 4 that that method is a test.  You had no such annotations, so JUnit found no tests to run, and hence reported an error message with the text 'no runnable methods'.